# TSQL retreive the next item if item has already been assigned

Tags: sql, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group, recursive-query

I have a sample data set which looks like:

[image]

I need to return the next value if the value hasn't already been taken.

I would like to achieve this by not using a cursor. The data which should be returned is highlighted in yellow.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear from your example how you identify which row to return.  Can you be more explicit in defining it?

Comment: How do you define "next value"?  What "value is not already taken"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using a recursive cte and window functions:

```
with 
    tab as (
        select 
            t.*, 
            dense_rank() over(order by item) drn
        from mytable t
    ),
    cte as (
        select t.* from tab t where drn = 1
        union all
        select t.*
        from tab t
        inner join cte c on t.drn = c.drn + 1 and t.itemb > c.itemb
    )
select select item, itemb, date
from cte c
where itemb = (select min(itemb) from cte c1 where c1.item = c.item)
```

Derived table `tab` assigns ranks to each record according to `item` (records having the same `item` get the same rank).

Then, the recursive cte starts from the rows corresponding to the first `item`, and processes `item`s one by one, ensuring that the "next" `itemb` is greater than the preceding.

Finally, the outer query filters on the first `itemb` per `item`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13c1b14511be1d0665b6a6adc1763476)**:

```
item | itemb | date      
:--- | :---- | :---------
X    | A     | 2014-01-01
Y    | B     | 2014-01-02
Z    | C     | 2014-01-02
```